# AWK count/sort/unique audit.log CentOS 7

Tags: regex, linux, bash, apache, awk

I'm not familiar with awk, and im not sure where to begin.. basically im trying to extract specific data from `/var/log/audit/audit.log` the data is ip addresses, but they must be unique, meaning non repetitive, they must be sorted, and i need a count of the number of occurrences. Is this possible all in one step? I would like to create a two column table in html with one side having the ip address, while other having the number of occurrences.

Here is the awk command i have so far..

```
cat audit.log | awk '
    {
        match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)
        ip = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        print ip
    }
'
```

This command just prints out a million ip addresses, can someone help me out? im confused with awk.

Here is an example of the audit.log file used by the sshd daemon:

```
    exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=10.10.125.30 addr=45.60.145.130 terminal=ssh res=success'
    type=USER_LOGOUT msg=audit(1444401905.624:127): pid=1862 uid=0 auid=0 ses=1 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=102.10.145.130 addr=45.20.120.10 terminal=ssh res=success'
    type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1444401905.627:128): pid=1862 uid=0 auid=0 ses=1 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=102.30.145.130 addr=45.60.45.120 terminal=ssh res=success'
    type=USER_START msg=audit(1444401905.627:129): pid=1862 uid=0 auid=0 ses=1 msg='op=login id=0 exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=102.60.145.130 addr=108.60.145.130 terminal=ssh res=success'
    type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1444401905.629:130): pid=18799 uid=0 auid=0 ses=1 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=93:e4:a2:20:d9:41:44:1b:8a:ee:53:d8:c3:d5:06:27 direction=? spid=18799 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=108.60.145.130 terminal=? res=success'
    type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1444401905.629:131): pid=18799 uid=0 auid=0 ses=1 msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=f7:07:aa:ec:70:56:0f:e9:a9:24:25:97:53:4c:fb:1f direction=? spid=18799 suid=0  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=18.20.125.130 terminal=? res=success'

thanks
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input text? This would allow people not directly familiar with CentOS to post answers too.

Comment: Isn't it enough to append to your script this `|sort|uniq -c`? (Is this count one step?)

Comment: i added some input text so you can see

Comment: i need to count the occurrences of each unique ip address, and sort them.. basically im planning on having a <span> element that will hold this awk command for the ip address in one table cell, while the other table cell will have the number of occurrences for that particular ip.. hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print ip}' audit.log|sort -u
```

---

Your example output:

```
10.10.125.30
102.10.145.130
102.30.145.130
102.60.145.130
108.60.145.130
18.20.125.130
```

Comment: i also need the number of occurances per ip address.

Comment: cat audit.log | awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print ip}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20